# ASP.NET MVC 2 and sparkviewengine rendering single quotes to double quotes in html5 data- attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html, spark-view-engine

I'm having a problem with adding a json value as a data-attribute in a html5 page.

We use the spark view engine (v1.5) in our asp.net mvc 2.0 website.

The following viewcode:

```
<a href='${Url.Action("edit", new { id = vehicle.VehicleId })}' title='Bewerken' class='dialog dialog-edit' data-dialogoptions='{"beforeOpen":"initAlarmZoneForm"}'><span class="silk-icon silk-icon-page-edit"></span></a>
```

is being rendered as:

```
<a href="/Alarm/AlarmZone/edit/4" title="Bewerken" class="dialog dialog-edit" data-dialogoptions="{"beforeOpen":"initAlarmZoneForm"}"><span class="silk-icon silk-icon-page-edit"></span></a>
```

**note the enclosing double quotes in data-dialogoptions**

A single quote is required to generate a valid json-string in the data-dialogoptions attribute.

Does anyone know what is causing this behavior and how I can change or work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is more of a workaround than an answer, you don't really need to get spark to render single quotes.  You could use `&#x22;` escape character which `JSON.parse` seems to parse correctly.

[Here's a really basic example of it running.](http://jsfiddle.net/brJX5/)

---

Looks like you're seeing this behavior due to a [bug/feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329666/stop-sparkview-escaping-html/6340997#6340997) in the Spark view engine.

---

As of version [1.6](https://github.com/SparkViewEngine/spark/commit/9987ebaf6d8373d110f84548bdc9d3fc29a4c615), this "feature" was "fixed".  Spark should now properly preserve single/double quotes.

Comment: Thx, I've created an html helper for this.